# How do I remove text strings from a variable length cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a list of projects, their IDs all start with m, but the ID lengths are variable. Following the IDs are the project names, all varying lengths of text. I want to remove the project names from the descriptions. What are my best options? An example of what I have and what I need to see are below:

What I have:

```
m45675 Build cottages
m84956873844 Remove creek debris
m679548 Build access road to main Hwy
```

What I need to see:

```
m45675
m84956873844
m679548
```

Comment: SO you just need to remove all the text after the first space? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

Good Day,

In your examples you are looking for all information before the first space. Assuming all are in there own cell in the same column this should be fairly easy to do using a combination of the  LEFT and FIND formulas.  This formula use find to find the first space and LEFT to take all the information from before that space.

Please see the screen cap below.

[image]

I hope this helps,

Brad

Comment: `IFERROR(..., A1)`

Comment: Also, just FYI, FIND defaults to a starting position of 1; the last parameter is needed only if you want to start looking later in the string.

Comment: Billiant!! Worked perfectly! Thank you Brad!

Comment: Glad to hear it worked for you.